# token is not valid in nodejs when I delete an object in angular

Tags: node.js, jwt, token

when I delete an object from the frontend I get a httperrorresponse status 404: error "el token no es valido"

middleware jwt in nodejs

```
'use strict'

var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var moment = require('moment');
var secret = "klave";

exports.authenticated = function(req, res, next) {

    // Comprobar si llega autorización
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(403).send({
            message: 'La petición no tiene la cabecera de authorization'
        });
    }

    // Limpiar el token y quitar comillas
    var token = req.headers.authorization.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
    console.log(token); //line 18


    try {
        // Decodificar token
        var payload = jwt.decode(token, secret);
        // Adjuntar usuario identificado a request
        // req.user = payload;

        // Pasar a la acción
        //   next();

        // Comprobar si el token ha expirado
        if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: 'El token ha expirado'
            });
        }

    } catch (ex) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'El token no es válido'
        });
    }

    // Adjuntar usuario identificado a request
    req.user = payload;

    // Pasar a la acción
    next();

};
```

in console.log(token) line 18 I get `{token:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1ZjAyNWMxOGU0Y2IyMDIxYTgwNTVmZjYiLCJuYW1lIjoibWFydGEiLCJzdXJuYW1lIjoibWFydGEiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcnRhQG1hcnRhLmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOIiwiaW1hZ2UiOm51bGwsImlhdCI6MTYwMjg1MDQwM30.89vDC_PaQG733gL6aW1kV1t5HaDfPfJD-0DiyDvSUdw}`

without " " but must I quit { token: from the token only the value eyj0EXaIoIj.......????

Comment: data the token has when it was signed with private key if any of it is missing when you validate it again with the private key it will not validate. data must not change in token that is main purpose of it so don't change your token

Comment: but why then the private key is missing? if that is the problem?